# ValueError time data does not match format Python 2 datetime.strptime

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

The following code:

```
print getLastCheckin()
print type(getLastCheckin())
d1 = datetime.strptime(getLastCheckin(), '%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S')
print (d1)
```

outputs

```
(datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 3, 11, 7, 44),)
<type 'str'>

ValueError: time data '(datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 3, 11, 7, 45),)' does not match format '%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S'
```

My date format appears to be correct as far as I can tell.  What super obvious mistake am I not seeing?

On second thought, it seems the mysql select function is returning a strange datatype (maybe a tuple) that I need to Properly convert to a string without all of the parentheses first?

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the first element of the tuple, converting it to a string, then extracting those timestamp elements out using datetime worked!

Now I'm getting another issue that I will post :)